# How to install image_science on Mac OSX Lion using brew

Tags: mac, osx-lion

I want to install `image_science` on Mac OSX Lion
How to install image_science on Mac OSX Lion using brew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  was attempting to install imageScience and FreeImage on Lion, but was thwarted by the error :

> patching file Makefile.fip
> Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/patch -f -p1 -i 001-homebrew.diff

Per the discussion on this GitHub thread ...

> https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/7320

I replaced the included FreeImage formula with one from this gist :

> https://gist.github.com/1403082

$ mv /usr/local/Library/Formula/freeimage.rb /usr/local/Library/Formula/freeimage-original.rb
$ mv ~/freeimage_new_gist.rb /usr/local/Library/Formula/freeimage.rb

And was then able to brew FreeImage successfully :

> ==> gnumake -f Makefile.gnu
>
> ==> gnumake -f Makefile.gnu install INCDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/freeimage/3.15.1/include INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/freeimage/3.15.1/lib
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/freeimage/3.15.1: 4 files, 8.8M, built in 55 seconds

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [`image_science`](https://github.com/seattlerb/image_science):

> ImageScience is a clean and happy Ruby library that generates
>   thumbnails

Then this is actually a Gem for Ruby and no binary that is distributed through Homebrew. You install it with:

```
gem install image_science
```

It seems to have a runtime dependency on [FreeImage](http://sf.net/projects/freeimage), which you install through:

```
brew install freeimage
```

Comment: It's even [Homebrew aware](https://github.com/seattlerb/image_science/commit/1816f8c61cedf5df0f1cf6b8db347a4994745619)!